# Boas práticas (Refactoring) - melhor maneira de tratar um método com for dentro de outro

Tags: java, loop

Pessoal usando boas prática em Java como devo converter esse método?
Devo quebrar em vários métodos e dentro de cada um deles fazer o for?

```
public void salvarObjetos(Objeto objeto){

   for(Objeto1 obj : container.getList()){
        .
        .
        .
        ObjetoManager.save(obj);
        for(Objeto2 obj2 : obj.getLitObj()){
            .
            .
            .
            Objeto2Manager.save(obj2);
            for(Objeto3 obj3 : obj2.getListObj2()){
                .
                .
                .
                Objeto3Manager.save(obj3);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A questão de um `for` dentro de outro cria uma [complexidade ciclomática](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complexidade_ciclom%C3%A1tica) muito alta. Mais em miúdos, uma carga mental grande para poder entender o quê o método deve fazer.

Você pode utilizar algumas técnicas descritas no livro "Clean Code" do uncle Bob ( o título é maior mas procurando por "clean code" já vai achar, o autor é o Robert C. Martin ).

Basicamente ele sugere que você crie um método para cada `for` **e** tente ser o mais claro possível no nome do método.

Eu iria por este caminho:

```
public void salvarObjetos(Objeto objeto) {
   for(Objeto1 obj : container.getList()) {
        ObjetoManager.save(obj);
        salvarObjetos2(obj.getLitObj);
    }
}

private void salvarObjetos2(List<Objeto2> obj2List) {
  for(Objeto2 obj2 : obj2List){
    Objeto2Manager.save(obj2);
    salvarObjetos3(obj2.getListObj2());  
  }
}

private void salvarObjetos3(List<Objeto3> obj3List) {
  for(Objeto3 obj3 : obj2.getListObj2()){
    Objeto3Manager.save(obj3);
  }
}
```

Lembrando que você deve tentar descrever da melhor forma possível os nomes dos métodos e não só algo como `salvarObjetosX` claro que se somente persistir um objeto no banco de dados então não há como escrever de outra forma.

Repare que da forma que dividi o código fica menos *carregado* de entender cada conteúdo do `for`, digo isso pois normalmente não é só um método por `for`, há também atribuições de valores, verificações de condições...

Onde eu trabalho a gente tem uma meta de que cada método não deve ter mais que 15 linhas, se tiver deve haver um bom motivo. Ficamos vagando em ser consistentes com nossas regras de desenvolvimento ou flexíveis com elas.

Comment: Show, era oq eu pensava mesmo. já iniciei a leitura do livro código limpo. Me deparei com o código desse exemplo na empresa que eu entrei. Perguntei pra ter certeza de chegar e sugerir as mudanças. muito obrigado.

Comment: @FernandoLopes Se gostou da resposta poderia votar? Faz parte da comunidade indicar boas respostas ou indicar respostas ruins.

Comment: I sorry... havia me esquecido. pena não poder ainda marcar com ponto positivo. vlw

Comment: ahhh... sim... eu já votei na sua pergunta pq ela ajuda muita gente com a mesma dúvida... hehehehe